# python: reference "private" variables' names in an organized way

Tags: python, obfuscation, private

Suppose I have a class, and I want to reference some elements in the ' `__dict__` (for instance, I want to copy the dict and delete the attribute that cannot be pickled), *from inside the class*.

Problem is, those attributes are "private" so my code ends up looking like so

```
class MyClasss(object):
    def __init__(self):
          self.__prv=1
    def __getstate__(self):
          ret=self.__dict__.copy()
          del ret['_MyClass__prv']
```

I reference the class name explicitly in the del statement, which looks a little ugly for me.
Is there something nicer? something like `MyClass.getPrivateString('prv')`

Of course I can implement one myself, but I would be surprised if there isn't a builtin to surpass this problem.

Comment: There are no private attributes in Python as your scare-quotes seem to show you know. I suspect (but don't know) that double underscore mangling was to prevent inadvertent access to the `__machinery__` attributes like `__getstate__`.

Comment: @msw [mangling only happens if an attribute begins with two underscores AND DOES NOT end with two underscores.](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) Special attributes like `__getstate__` are NOT mangled.

Comment: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has a lot to say about naming conventions and when to use single- and double-underscores in names. I wouldn't use double-underscores in this situation.

Comment: The reason there isn't anything built in is that you are mistakenly thinking that `__` has something to to with private variables.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you don't copy 'private' attributes, won't the copy of your object behave differently from the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I used a variant of thieger's solution

```
del ret["_%s__%s" % (MyClasss.__name__, "prv")]
```

I think this is the most robust way I can write that piece of code, aside from giving up the mangling, which might be the right thing to do, but I was asking what to do in case you actually have mangling :)

Answer (score 6):

Consider using only a single underscore for private attributes. These are still considered private but do not get name mangled.

```
class MyClasss(object):
    def __init__(self):
          self._prv=1
    def __getstate__(self):
          ret=self.__dict__.copy()
          del ret['_prv']
```

Comment: thanks, I might use that tip.
but I would really like to get an answer for my original question, with the mangling :)

Comment: Check my answer, I tried to deal with the name mangling in another way.

Comment: @noam: isn't that like asking for an pain-killer so it hurts less while you are hitting yourself with a hammer? @jon-eric: thanks for the pointer to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to create a copy of the object, erase its private attributes and then return its `__dict__`, something like:

```
class X:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__prv = 0

  def del_privates(self):
    del self.__prv

  def __getstate__(self):
    other = X()
    other.__dict__ = self.__dict__.copy()
    other.del_privates()
    return other.__dict__
```

After calling `__getstate__`, the returned dict will not have the `__prv` member, since it gets erased when `other.del_privates()` is called.

Comment: I know it's better, the name mangling is there for some reason. However, I answered because the OP asked how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut, but if you just want to avoid naming the class explicitly, you can do something like:

```
del ret["_%s__%s" % (self.__class__.__name__, "prv")]
```

Comment: This breaks with subclassing.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use your own naming convention for those attributes, such as `_prv_x`, `_prv_y` etc. then you can use a loop to selectively remove them

```
class MyClasss(object):
    def __init__(self):
          self._prv_x=1
          self._prv_y=1
    def __getstate__(self):
          return dict((k,v) for k,v in vars(self).items() if not k.startswith("_prv_"))
```

In python2.7+

```
    def __getstate__(self):
          return {k:v for k,v in vars(self).items() if not k.startswith("_prv_")}
```

Comment: Uh, this convention already exists: a single leading underscore.

Comment: @Aaron, the OP needs a way to distinguish variables that are not to be pickled. Zope uses the same idea.

Comment: so why not use the established convention of a single leading underscore?

Comment: @Aaron, perhaps some of the private variables _do_ need to be pickled. This way they still match the convention of having a single leading underscore, but also have a mini-namespace with a special purpose